spatial temporal interpolarization
Assume I have a spatial temporal dataframe which looks like:
# Load necessary libraries
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Create a simple spatial polygon grid
polygons <- st_make_grid(
  st_bbox(c(xmin = 0, ymin = 0, xmax = 10, ymax = 10)), 
  cellsize = c(2, 2),
  square = TRUE
) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(poly_id = row_number())  # Add polygon identifiers

# Create a temporal variable with years
years <- seq(2000, 2005)

# Expand grid to simulate spatiotemporal data
spatiotemporal_data <- expand.grid(
  poly_id = polygons$poly_id,
  year = years
) %>%
  left_join(polygons, by = "poly_id") %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Add a variable with some NA values
set.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
spatiotemporal_data <- spatiotemporal_data %>%
  mutate(variable = ifelse(runif(n()) > 0.8, NA, rnorm(n())),
         variable = if_else(poly_id == 3, NA, variable))

Now I would like first: do an temporal inter-/ extrapoliation within a poly_id. However I'm able to do run the temporal interpolarization by:
patiotemporal_data <- spatiotemporal_data %>%
  arrange(poly_id, year) %>% 
  group_by(poly_id) %>% 
         mutate(across(variable, ~ ifelse(any(!is.na(.)), zoo::na.approx(., na.rm = TRUE, rule = 2),. ))) %>% 
  ungroup()

Now I want to fill the remaing NAs (in Group 3, as no variable was given) by spatial interpolariation.
Approaches I found yet, using e.g. point to interpolate on a grid. But what if I just want to fill the NAs? thanks.

What's the rule for the fill?

I hope to get you right: but I thought at something like IDW function from sptatstat package, obvious based on the year. However, I'm even open to other apporaches to fill the NAs "reasonable" by neighboring grids.

Ok, sounds like you want some sort of kriging.

All years in example are currently the same, was this intentional - https://i.sstatic.net/eAzhyn0v.png ?

No sorry, just tried to do an easy reproducible sample. As my orginial data are more complicated. So considering years would be important.
